# How to combine multiple rows per ID into a single row for a particular column?

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, concatenation

```
ID  NAME                        INPUTS
2   ABCD                        First Name
2   ABCD                        Last Name
3   1234                        First Name
3   1234                        Last Name
6   QWERTY                      First Name
6   QWERTY                      Last Name
```

Above is what the Select statement returns.

I would like the select statement to return one row per ID combining the last column "Inputs".

I currently am using a very basic select statement but this select statement is returning over 5,000 rows when it should be returning less than half of that number.

Comment: How are you guaranteeing that firstname precedes lastname? Something is needed to enforce that order. Are there always 2 values for inputs?

Answer (score 0):

```
     declare @YourTable table (RowID int, ID int, name varchar(100), inputs varchar(500))
insert into @YourTable VALUES (1,2,'ABCD', 'First Name')
insert into @YourTable VALUES (2,2,'ABCD', 'Last Name')
insert into @YourTable VALUES (3,3,'1234', 'First Name')
insert into @YourTable VALUES (4,3,'1234','Last Name')
--insert into @YourTable VALUES (5,3,'A & Z')
set nocount off
SELECT
    t1.id, t1.name
        ,STUFF(
                   (SELECT
                        ', ' + t2.inputs
                        FROM @YourTable t2
                        WHERE t1.id=t2.id
                        ORDER BY t2.inputs
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                   ).value('.','varchar(max)')
                   ,1,2, ''
              ) AS inputs
    FROM @YourTable t1
    GROUP BY  t1.id, t1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like

```
select p.[ID], p.[First Name], p.[Last Name], isnull(p.[First Name], '') + ' ' + isnull(p.[Last Name], '') [FullName]
from
(
    select t.[ID], t.[NAME], t.[INPUTS]
    from [dbo].[YourTable] t
) x
pivot
(
    max(x.[NAME]) for x.[INPUTS] in ([First Name], [Last Name])
) p
```

This will handle most cases:

- No `First Name`
- No `Last Name`
- No name at all

Even though some improvements can be done for special cases

Comment: Sébastien Sevrin - what if the number of  'input' values differ for IDs? ID: 2 has 2 inputs values and ID: 6 has 5 inputs value. for this condition your query will fail.

Comment: @kiki47 - I don't see your point, but anyway that's not even specified in the OP. I said in my post that "some improvements can be done for special cases", and I think that it's best to keep the query as simple as possible and change it only if it's necessary.

Comment: I think the code should be reliable and should be able to accept different conditions.

Comment: Sébastien Sevrin- the query is not reliable it will fail if the input value changes!! good bye